# Why does refreshing webpage gives "Cannot GET /history"?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a website with frontend built with React.js and backend built with Node.js and Express.
I copied the `build` directory generated by `npm run build` from frontend to my backend root directory so that I can run both the backend API and frontend locally from the same port 3001.

The `build` directory is served using [express.static()](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

```js
// app.js
const config = require("./utils/config");

const express = require("express");
const app = express();

require("express-async-errors");

const cors = require("cors");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const helmet = require("helmet");

app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan("tiny"));
app.use(helmet());

const blogsRouter = require("./controllers/blogs");
const usersRouter = require("./controllers/users");
const loginRouter = require("./controllers/login");

const middleware = require("./utils/middleware");
const logger = require("./utils/logger");

const { tokenExtractor, userExtractor } = require("./utils/middleware");

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

logger.info("connecting to", config.MONGODB_URI);

mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);
mongoose
  .connect(config.MONGODB_URI)
  .then(() => {
    logger.info("connected to MongoDB");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    logger.error("error connecting to MongoDB:", error.message);
  });

// Serve static files from the React app
const path = require("path");
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));

app.use(express.json());

// Register the routers
app.use(
  "/api/v1/blogs",
  tokenExtractor,
  userExtractor,
  blogsRouter
);
app.use("/api/v1/users", usersRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/login", loginRouter);

// handler of requests which result to errors
// this has to be the last loaded middleware
app.use(middleware.errorHandler);

module.exports = app;
```

Backend directory structure:

[image]

The frontend is perfectly served at `http://localhost:3001` and all the links routed using react router works.
There is a link which takes me to `http://localhost:3001/history` which perfectly serves the respective frontend webpage but when I refresh the page or directly enter the route in the address bar, I get the following errors:

In the browser:

```
Cannot GET /history
```

In the developer console:
[image]

How to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure about the React or node but can we run two programs on same port?

Comment: @Utkarsh If we build the frontend and serve the static files in backend using `express.static()`. See https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: The server/backend should redirect all page requests by serving the root index.html file. Can you [edit] the post to include a more complete and comprehensive [mcve] of the backend code serving the app?

Comment: @DrewReese I have edited my `app.js` code in the question. Thanks.